# Using RediSearch with NRediSearch (C#), how to apply OR clause on two numeric fields like i.CountyId == id || i.CityId == id

Tags: c#, redis, redisearch

I am developing a `.Net Core` web app with RediSearch. Previously I have used in-app memory cache, but I have to change it to distributed cache. The issue is, the web app has very complex searches which must be handled from cache. I though I just move the cache to `Redis` and must filter in `Linq` will stay the same just as with in-app memory cache, but if you have 500K+ entries in Redis, using a docker image on the same host took around 4 sec just to load these entries into a variable so this is not an option.

I have now implemented `RediSearch` with `NRediSearch` which seem to handle the load pretty well. The issue I have now, I have a search with multiple location fields.

Example

```
class Item{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int CountyId {get;set;}
    public int CityId {get;set;}
}
class Location{
    public int LocationId {get;set;}
    public bool IsCounty {get;set;}
}
```

I need to translate the following `Linq` command into `RediSearch`

```
public List<Item> Search(List<Location> location){
    var result = items.Where(i => location.Any(l => l.IsCounty && l.Id == i.CountyId) || location.Any(l => !l.IsCounty && i.CityId == l.Id))
}
```

I have read the `RediSearch` documentation, but have not found any answer yet. I have to do this in one search because of sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found he answer.

```
FT.SEARCH idx "@title|body:(hello world) @url|image:mydomain"
```

Probably if `NRediSearch` can handle this or operator within a new query, if not, must be implemented straight through it's client

Comment: PRs welcomed :) note you can use Execute on the database to issue ad-hoc commands, as a workaround

Answer (score 0):

you can use my library i build over nredisearch. but it works for simple linq queries. its not work on nested objects. I will be glad if you contribute to its development.

if we talk about your example you have to duplicate your data for each location like this:

```
class Item {

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int CountyId {get;set;}
    public int CityId {get;set;}
    public int LocationId {get;set;}
    public bool IsCounty {get;set;}
}
```

and you can search this daha with my library.

[RedisworkCore](https://github.com/hizliemre/redisworkcore)

PackageManager:

`Install-Package RedisworkCore`

Dotnet CLI:

`dotnet add package RedisworkCore`

and you can create context like entityframework:

```
public class Person
{
    [RedisKey(0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}

public class SimpleContext : RedisContext
{
    public Rediset<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public SimpleContext(RedisContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
}
```

then you can use Find, Where, Any, All, SortBy, SortByDescending, Skip, Take similar LINQ.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{

  RedisContextOptions options = new RedisContextOptions
  {
    HostAndPort = "localhost:6379"
  };

  using (var context = new SimpleContext(options))
  {
    var person = new Person
    {
      Id = 26,
      Name = "Emre",
      Lastname = "Hızlı"
    };
    context.Persons.Add(person);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
  }

  using (var context = new SimpleContext(options))
  {
    Person person = await context.Persons.Find(26);
    List<Person> persons = await context.Persons.Where(x => x.Id > 0).ToListAsync();
  }
  
}
```

Notes:

- You should save your data with redisworkcore otherwise it won't work.
- Performance tests were not conducted. It may work better if I can get support as open source.